# Why is there not a cancel link when editing on the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, editing, mobile-web

[This question appears to be new.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cancel+mobile+site+edit)

> Why is there not a cancel link when editing answers or questions on the mobile (meta) site?

It's absence isn't exactly obvious (as I haven't noticed it until now, having used stack exchange mobile sites for a good few years; I don't know about you). I think one can cancel edits to one's own comments in the mobile site though (but I'll delete this sentence if not).

The option to cancel an edit is, of course, present on the desktop sites, so why not the mobile sites?

(I haven't checked this feature on the app yet.)

The option would save users from having to delete lengthy, erroneous edit drafts to answers and questions that require better edits.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [Mobile Edit Cancel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161117)

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewT. That answers my question nicely.